# gitlab ci yml run specific stage for release candidate branch only

Tags: gitlab-ci

Hi I have a yml as below but i want to run specific stage for only specific branch names like release candidate. The name of the release branch can change like cis-rel1.0 the next time cis-rel2.0 and so on.

```
image: java:8

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./mvnw package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - curl --location "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github" | tar zx
  - ./cf login -u $CF_USERNAME -p $CF_PASSWORD -a api.run.pivotal.io
  - ./cf push
  only:
  - cis-rel1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that using the regex pattern in .gitlab-ci.yml as shown below . This regex will filter for your project name `/^cis-rel.*$/`

```
image: java:8

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./mvnw package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - curl --location "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github" | tar zx
  - ./cf login -u $CF_USERNAME -p $CF_PASSWORD -a api.run.pivotal.io
  - ./cf push
  only:
  - /^cis-rel.*$/
```